# Add list to object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, blazor

I have two Models called "Client" and "Software". Clients can have the same Software and Software can be on multiple clients. I want to add a List of Software to a specific Client.

**Client Model:**

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public ICollection<Software>? Softwares { get; set; }
    }
```

**Software Model:**

```
public class Software
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Client>? Clients { get; set; }
    }
```

**Why does this throw a NullReferenceException?**

```
public void submit()
        {
            using (var repo = new ClientRepository(contextFactory.CreateDbContext()))
            {
                client = repo.getClientByID(Convert.ToInt32(clientid));

                foreach (var software in toAddList)
                {
                    client.Softwares.Add(software); //Error occurs here
                }

            }               
        }
```

**Repo Code**

```
public Client getClientByID(int id)
        {
            return _context.Clients.Find(id);
        }
```

Comment: add `repo.getClientByID(Convert.ToInt32(clientid));` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to include `Softwares` when fetching from Clients table in database

In your repo, change your code to be like this :

```
public Client getClientByID(int id)
{
     return _context.Clients.Include(k => k.Softwares).Single(i => i.id == id);
}
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman, For me since it is already an Id I would just use First(), because I am confident that there is only data anyway by the virtue of database constrain itself, no need for database to scan throught entire table to check for any possible duplicate during this data retrieval.

Comment: Alright, I will edit my code

Answer (score 1):

Here, two objects can be `null`, both the `client` itself and the `software` list, But your error occurs because the list of `software` is `null`, to solve this problem you need to load the list of `software` when receiving `Client` information from the database,But before that, you must make sure of the existence of the `Client`.
solve it as follows:

```
public Client getClientByID(int id)
{
    return _context.Clients.Include(s=>s.Softwares).FirstOrDefault(u => u.id == id);
}

client = repo.getClientByID(Convert.ToInt32(clientid));

if(client is null)
{
   //Do somthing Like Return or throw new Exception
}

foreach (var software in toAddList)
{
  client.Softwares.Add(software);
}
```